# problem with protected method in spring using MappingMediaTypeFileExtensionResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file-extension, media-type

I'm having a doubt using this class in SpringBoot application **MappingMediaTypeFileExtensionResolver**,
i want get the mediatype form file extension but the only method that i need is protected (
**lookupMediaType(String extension)** )
I can implement the method directly but Im looking for a better solution.

```
Map<String, MediaType> mapping =  new HashMap<String, MediaType>();
mapping.put("PDF", MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
mapping.put("TEXT", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
MappingMediaTypeFileExtensionResolver resolver = new MappingMediaTypeFileExtensionResolver(mapping);


this.fileType = resolver.lookupMediaType("JSON");
```

how can i access it if Im in another package?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this method is meant to be used internally by springframework. But you can create a public method ina simple class which extends **MappingMediaTypeFileExtensionResolver**, code as below:

```
public class MediaTypeDemoResolver extends MappingMediaTypeFileExtensionResolver {

public MediaTypeDemoResolver(Map<String, MediaType> mediaTypes) {
    super(mediaTypes);
}

public MediaType lookupMediaType(String extension) {
    return super.lookupMediaType(extension);
}}
```

Use the above public method instead :

```
Map<String, MediaType> mapping = new HashMap<>();
    mapping.put("PDF", MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    mapping.put("TEXT", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    MediaTypeDemoResolver resolver = new MediaTypeDemoResolver(mapping);

    this.fileType = resolver.lookupMediaType("JSON");
```

Hope this helps.